# Hardhat Ethers Address is not returning correct Value

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js

I'm doing a hardhat test and using the addresses from the hardhat node I've up.

```js
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
let owner_balance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);
console.log(owner.address);
console.log(owner_balance.toString());
owner_balance = ethers.utils.formatEther(owner_balance);
console.log(owner_balance);
```

The balance is not the correct balance from what the node says the address has which is 10k eth. This is what is returning from the console.log and code above.
https://gyazo.com/a94219ae7e39cf75bf9eb6a2df787b82

This is the node and the same address that shows 10k eth in it - https://gyazo.com/b1f88a8f482c254d333728fc19916f20

Answer (score 0):

I encounteres similar issue, but i realized that i was using the polygon network, and the amount was correct in MATIC, not ETH.

maybe this helps